# How we get FireBase For following Structure

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get message particular from Firebase. [image]
I want get all message of particular reference 2425. I am unable to get this. Please help .

Comment: Please do not include images in your questions. Include code and structures as text. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy an paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following to retrieve the message:

```
  let ref = self.myRootRef.child(byAppendingPath: "2425")!

ref.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

        for child in (snapshot?.children)! {
            let snap = child as! FDataSnapshot
            let dict = snap.value as! [String: String]
            let message = dict["message"]
       }
})
```

Here the snapshot is at child `2425` then you attach a listener to it and iterate inside it's the  ids generated by `childByAutoId()` and retrieve the "message" `let message = dict["message"]`

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new child node under the same parent node
`let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://<baseUser>.firebaseio.com/").child("Users").child("Users").childByAutoId()`